# Regeln für das Geschlecht von Indefinita bzw. indefiniten Nominalphrasen

Tags: gender, grammar-identification, indefinite-pronoun

Gibt es Regeln, welche das korrekte Genus des zu verwendenden Numerals in Indefinita betreffen? Hier sind zwei Beispiele:

> Zur Auswahl stehen mir die Gabel, das Messer und der Löffel. *(Eine|einen|eines)*? davon wähle ich.

> Den Laden betraten eine Frau, ein Mann und ein Kind. *(Eines|einer|eine)*? davon kam wieder heraus.

An einschlägigem Material habe ich lediglich [Genuswechsel in Kopulasätzen](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/249937908_Genuswechsel_in_Kopulasatzen_und_die_Bedeutung_indefiniter_Nominalphrasen/fulltext/5fb43ab945851518fdb058cc/Genuswechsel-in-Kopulasaetzen-und-die-Bedeutung-indefiniter-Nominalphrasen.pdf) (PDF) gefunden, das aber das Thema auch nicht erschöpfend behandelt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duden - Die Grammatik (8. Auflage 2009) sagt dazu unter Randnummer 1596:

> Die Neutrumformen der Pronomen kennen einige besondere Gebrauchsweisen:
>
> (...)
>
> - Vereinzelnde Lesart:
>
>   *Das Messer und die Gabeln* stechen, drum rühre *keins* von beiden an! *Fundevogel und Lenchen* hatten einander so lieb, dass, wenn *eins das andere* nicht sah, *es* traurig war.
>
>   Bei Nennung mehrerer Personen mit verschiedenem Geschlecht steht heute aber meist die maskuline Form des Pronomens: *Die Professorin und ihr Assistent unterschrieben, jeder war zufriedengestellt.*

Dementsprechend würde man sagen,

> Zur Auswahl stehen mir die Gabel, das Messer und der Löffel. *Eines* davon wähle ich.

und, weil es sich um Personen verschiedenen Geschlechts handelt,

> Den Laden betraten eine Frau, ein Mann und ein Kind. *Einer* davon kam wieder heraus.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Genau danach habe ich gesucht (und - offensichtlich nicht gut genug).

Answer (score -2):

Hammer's German Grammar and Usage: 1.1.12b: Neuter singular pronouns are used to refer to male and female persons.

> Sie stehen eine Weile schweigend, jedes die Hand auf der Schulter des anderen. (Fallada).

Comment: Warum antwortest du auf Englisch wenn die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt wurde? Du kannst nicht wissen, ob der/die Fragesteller*in diese Fremdsprache überhaupt versteht, aber du weißt mit Sicherheit, dass er/sie ziemlich gut Deutsch beherrscht.

Comment: Because I have little confidence in my German.

Comment: Und trotzdem glaubst du, eine Antwort auf diese schwierige Frage parat zu haben? Von der von dir zitierten Regel habe ich noch nie gehört und ich spreche meine Muttersprache nun schon seit mehr als einem halben Jahrhundert.

Comment: I find I only learn by making mistakes. I apologize if that is disturbing.

Answer (score -5):

Ich kann die Frage nicht aus sprachwissenschaftlicher Sicht beantworten, weil ich nicht wüsste, wo ich nach Belegen suchen sollte, aber ich kann sie aus der Perspektive eines sprachinteressierten Muttersprachlers beantworten:

Ich würde sagen:

> 1. Zur Auswahl stehen mir die Gabel, das Messer und der Löffel. **Eines** davon wähle ich.
> 2. Den Laden betraten eine Frau, ein Mann und ein Kind. **Eine** davon kam wieder heraus.

#### Begründung:

Ich suche hier intuitiv nach einem Oberbegriff, unter dem sich die genannten Begriffe versammeln und verwende im Pronomen das Genus dieses Oberbegriffs. Diese Oberbegriffe sind:

1. Das Besteck (sächlich)
2. Die Person (weiblich)

Nachdem der Sender diese Oberbegriffe aber nicht explizit nennt, kann es passieren, dass der Empfänger der Nachricht intuitiv eine andere Wahl trifft (z.B. im Fall 2: der Mensch, männlich) und dann irritiert von der Genuswahl des Senders ist.

Weil hier das Genus aber eben von einem ungenannten Oberbegriff abhängt, der zwar Teil des Kontexts, aber eben trotzdem ungenannt ist, werden Sprecher meist vermeiden, solche Konstruktionen anzuwenden.

Comment: Wenn man nichts über das Geschlecht weiß, sagt man bei Personen aber "einer": "Einer hat seinen Regenschirm vergessen", auch wenn uns Aktivisten glauben machen wollen, dass das ungerecht sei. Bei Besteck, wenn es eine Aufzählung mit 3 Geschlechtern gab, hört es sich jedoch, egal wie man's macht, falsch an. Wie so oft kann man dann ja umformulieren und sagen "Eines der Besteckstücke ..." oder "ein Ding/Objekt ..." oder "eine Sache wähle ich".

Comment: @userunknown: In diesem Fall würde ich *jemand* sagen: *»Jemand hat den Regenschirm vergessen.«* Und ich glaube den Aktivisten: Es ist ungerecht. Aber leider hat nie jemand versprochen, dass alles gerecht sein muss.

Comment: Okay, und "Jemand hat seinen Regenschirm vergessen und damit den schönen Teppich eingesaut!" *Seinen* oder wessen? *Den* Regenschirm vergessen ist ja in den seltensten Fällen richtig - welchen denn? Gab es nur einen?